# Is first wife's permission required for second marriage?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife

Some people claim that a married man cannot marry again till he gets permission from his first wife. I find that hard to believe. As much as I have studied this subject, I have not come across any such prerequisite for second marriage. I have heard about the equality and justness and fairness amongst all the wives but I don't understand how a wife would ever allow to share her love and allow her husband to go to another woman with her permission. (Exceptions may be one in a million).

But considering how little knowledge I have, I am inclined to ask others if they can provide references for such a claim?

Please provide references from Qur'an and Hadith or Sahaba's sayings. You can also provide reference from Four Imam's books/rulings where they put such a restriction.

I am looking for Sunni view but Shia views are welcomed too. (Please mention this along your answer)

P.S. A thought just hit my mind, if in case first wife's permission's requried for the second marriage, then what about the 3rd and 4th marriage? Do we need to ask permission from all the wives?

Comment: AFAIK and read scholars say that the permission of any wife isn't necessary but it's better to inform her/them (this is a point i would strongly accentuate, as i think that not informing could be  a reason for disharmony or talaq), as our Messenger peace be upon him never asked his wifes for permission.

Comment: I searched for the words similar to 'Permission for second marriage' so the above question didn't show up in the search hence I asked a question. It is indeed a duplicate but I will not delete this question so people can be redirected to that question when they use similar wording to mine to search for this issue.

Comment: This question will automatically be deleted after a while I suppose.